# Javascript Regular Expression not working right

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

In Javascript, I'm reading in a .txt file to parse and put into an HTML table. That's working perfectly fine. In that information, there are address lines, that are a combination of what would be the first and second lines (second being the apartment numbers, space numbers, etc.). It reads those off fine into a single line.
What I'm trying to do is break up what would be the first and second address lines so that it can be fed into a database cleanly. To break them up, I've written a regular expression to catch as many of the options as I can think of. Most of them work perfectly fine. One of them is refusing to work correctly, even though all of the testing with small examples say it should work.
Here's the section of the regular expression that I'm trying to work with: [Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/bC8aZ4/5)

Regex used:

```
([\,\s]*)(Ste |Ste\. )
```

On:

```
12 Watershore Circle
825 Stewart Street
820 N Lincoln Way
9235 Bella Vista Way
P.O. Box 4438
9936 Stone Oak Way
599 Hamstead Drive
3941 Park Drive Ste 20 #147
3609 Bradshaw RD,ste H #107
7909 Walerga Road, Ste. 112, PMB 108
```

Options I've tried for what I want:

```
([\,\s]*)(Ste |Ste\. )
([\,\s]+)(Ste |Ste\. )
(\,*[\W]Ste[\W]|\,*[\W]Ste\.[\W])
```

What the live results on my webpage seem to think these mean:

```
(\,*[\w]Ste[\w]|\,*[\w]Ste\.[\w])
```

or

```
([\,\s]*)(Ste|Ste\.)
```

As you can see, I'm just trying to separate the "Ste" (case insensitive) from the rest of the line. What is happening in the live test is that the lines are breaking on any instance of "Ste" (still case insensitive). The link I gave above has example regular expressions that generate what I'm getting from my live run.
This regular expression situation is in javascript code in an MVC 4 with Razor (c#) view page. Again, the rest of the regular expression that I haven't listed here that is looking for completely different phrasing works fine. It's just this one piece.
Any suggestions on how to properly debug this or any solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your regex searches for `Ste[space]` or `Ste[any character][space]`. You should always escape the `.` when you're aiming for a literal `.`, like `\.`. You can shorten your regex to  `([\,\s]*)(Ste\.? )` without seeing the code using these regexes.

Comment: Good catch on that typo of mine. I've changed it to the proper escape for the period. Unfortunately, this is still creating a problem on two cases. If I use it how you had it, for whatever reason, it will split words like "Allister", since the space and comma on the front are completely optional. If I change it to `([\,\s]+)(Ste\.? )` to force at least one of them to be in front, it can't find any matches, even though it should work according to the demo.

Comment: Probably won't change anything but you don't need to escape commas.

Comment: It doesn't change much, but thanks for the heads up on that :) it'll help reduce a little bit of the slash clutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently, Crazysheep, your comment was very important. It got me thinking about the escapes.
What I neglected to post in my question is that, in the javascript, I was not directly writing the regular expression as a regular expression. Due to the length of the line, I had written it in a String so I could break it across multiple lines, and then converted this String into the regular expression by means of 
`var re = new RegExp(reString,"gi");`
Because of this small little detail, all of the slash escapes were working like String escapes. This meant whenever I had `\.`, for String, it was doing a literal `.` and not the regular expression escape. This applied to all of the escapes.
The reason I noticed it at all was because for the piece that, in regular expression format, looked like this: `(\. \d+)`, it was breaking on every instant of something, a space, and a D. Ex: `3 Drive` or `a Dr.`
To fix this, in the String, for what would be `\.` in a regular expression, I have put `\\.`, in order to escape the `\` so it can function as it has to in the regular expression.
So, thank you Crazysheep, you have helped more than you can know! XD